# The greatest common divisor of homogeneous polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let a matrix $$M=\begin{pmatrix} a_{01}&a_{02}&a_{03}\\a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}$$ with $a_{ij}\in k[x,y,z]$ homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$.
 Let $p=(\lambda_0: \lambda_1:\lambda_2:\lambda_3)\in\mathbb P^3$ and we set
$F_j=\sum\limits_{i=0}^3\lambda_i a_{ij},\ \ \ j=1,2,3$.

Problem:

> How many points $p \in\mathbb P^3 $ such that the homogeneous polynomials $F_1,F_2,F_3$ have the greatest common divisor of the positive degree? (It is dependent on the degree $d$.)

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you choose $a_{ij}$ equal to the same polynomial $g$, the greatest common divisor of the $F_j$ will always be associated to $g$. Seems like this will heavily depend on the matrix $M$.

Comment: Thank Jesko Hüttenhain. It is sure that the gcd depend on the matrix $M$. But is there a idea to bound a number of the points $p\in P^3$ that depend on the coefficients of $a_{ij}$ and  degree $d$?

Comment: Where if we define the determinantal ideal $I$ of the matrix $M$ to be the ideal of $k[x,y,z]$ generated by all $3\times 3$-minors of $M$. We assume that the ideal $I$ is saturated and the projective variety $V(I)\subset \mathbb P^2$ is zero-dimensional, that is $V(I)$ is finite and locally a complete intersection.